# the number of multiplications per second required by the system

Tags: filter-design, sampling, finite-impulse-response, dsp-core, downsampling

Q1. Consider a system implementing a rational sampling rate change by 5/7: for this, we cascade upsampler by 5, a lowpass filter with cutoff frequency π/7 and a downsampler by 7. The lowpass filter is a 99-tap FIR.

Assume that the input works at a rate of 1000 samples per second. What is the number of multiplications per second required by the system? Assume that multiplications by zero do not count and round the number of operations to the nearest integer.

Please tell the approach on how to start this question.

The generic order of sampling rate change is "upsample", "filter", "downsample". That means that we need to run the filter at the upsampled rate, i.e 5000 but given that it is 99tap filter so shall i directly multiply 99*5000=495000. is it okay wrt the asked question or am i missing something

Comment: This question appears to be homework. Complete answers to homework are off-topic, but specific questions about homework are acceptable if they include enough detail. Please edit the question to include more background about what you don't understand.

Comment: IT WOULD BE A GREAT HELP IF YOU CAN TELL THE APPROACH TO SOLVE THIS QUESTION.

Comment: Hi DSP, your question for approach isn't any more narrow. Explain what you understand, and what **exactly** you need help with to come up with an approach of your own. (Also, "CAPS LOCK" is the internet way of *shouting*, and I don't think you meant to shout at me ;) )

Comment: sorry sir i do not mean to shout on you

Comment: don't worry, nothing bad happened :)

Comment: the only thing i need to ask is in how can we start solving this question coming with right result

Comment: so and how are we supposed to answer that? we don't know what you know, and we can't be starting to explain the very basics for 100 pages. That's why the rule is like it is (my first comment), and it is pretty clear, isn't it?

Comment: way better! Now we actually have something to answer! Can you **edit** your question to include what you've commented here?